# How can we publish Search Schema Managed Properties from SharePoint Online Content Type Hub site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search, managed-property, refiner, content-type-hub

I'm trying to achieve the below functionality, - SharePoint Online

Create a SharePoint Online Classic Search with Refiners and get results from Modern Team Site

1. From Content Type Hub Site publish Content Types (CT1) and attached Site Columns (A, B, c)
2. Mapped Crawled properties ows_A, ows_B, ows_c to refinable strings refinablestrin01, refinablestrin02, refinablestrin03
3. Publish Content Types from Content Type Hub
4. Created a Modern Team site with Document Library (D1) and attached content Type (CT1).
5. Uploaded documents to the library D1
6. Created a classic Enterprise Search site.
7. Created a custom search result source to fetch only content type (CT1) documents

****My issue is how to add refiners to the refiner web part. Will, it takes time to Crawl to see Managed properties refinable string in the Search site. ?***

***Can we publish managed properties from Content type Hub to Search and Modern Team site ?***

***How can I achieve refiners in the Search Site?****

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieved the above functionality by creating Refinable Managed Properties and mapping Crawled Properties at Individual Team Site level. We can't create Refinable Managed Properties at content type hub level and publish across all Site Collections.

I have mapped Crawled Properties to Refinable Managed Properties at Team Site level and now able to see the Refiners in Classic Search Site.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is Map crawled properties with refinable string in one site collection. Go to site settings --> Search Configuration Export, it will download SearchConfiguaration.xml. Now upload this xml in all other site collections using import option in the site settings like below

[image]